# How to protect service from gzip bomb?

Tags: json, http, security, go, gzip

I have `test.gzip` file with json

```
{"events": [
{"uuid":"56c1718c-8eb3-11e9-8157-e4b97a2c93d3",
"timestamp":"2019-06-14 14:47:31 +0000",
"number":732,
"user": {"full_name":"0"*1024*1024*1024}}]}
```

full_name filed contains 1GB of `0`, zipped filesize ~1Mb

how can I protect my service during unpacking so that my memory is not over?

```
func ReadGzFile(filename string) ([]byte, error) {
    fi, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer fi.Close()

    fz, err := gzip.NewReader(fi)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer fz.Close()

    s, err := ioutil.ReadAll(fz)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return s, nil
}

func main() {
    b, err := ReadGzFile("test.gzip")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    var dat map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dat)
}
```

In this case output can kill my service by OOMKiller

Comment: The first thing to do would be not to unzip into memory. This is usually good advice, regardless of zip bombs. What are you doing with the uncompressed content? Can you treat it like a stream?  If not, unzip to disk, instead of memory.

Comment: Worst case scenario, abort if the content is too large.

Comment: @Flimzy Even then, it is thinkable that the extracted size exceeds the disk space.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: That's true with or without a zip bomb. I would assume that's already being checked for, and/or disk-full errors are being handled properly.

Comment: In general, do not use `ReadAll`. Use `Read` insteadand determine a threshold of the size of data read thus far vs gzip filesize. If this compression ratio exceeds what can reasonably be expected, abort.

Comment: @frankegoesdown A REST API can use temporary files as good as literally every other piece of software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What can be deceiving is that the compressed size may be significantly smaller that the allowed size (the size you can or you wish to handle). In your example the input is about 1 MB, while the uncompressed size is about 1 GB.

While reading the *uncompressed* data you should stop after reaching a reasonable limit. To easily do that, you may use [`io.LimitReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitReader) where you can specify the max amount of bytes you wish to read. Yes, you have to wrap the *unzipped* stream, not the original, compressed stream.

This is an example how it would look like:

```
limited := io.LimitReader(fz, 2*1024*1024)

s, err := ioutil.ReadAll(limited)
```

The above example limits the readable data to 2 MB. What happens when the unzipped data is more than that? The `io.Reader` returned by `io.LimitReader()` (which is by the way an [`io.LimitedReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitedReader)) will report `io.EOF`. This protects your server from the attack, but might not be the best way to handle it.

Since you mentioned this is for a rest API, a better suited solution would be the similar [`http.MaxBytesReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader). This wraps the passed reader to read up until a given limit, and if that is reached, it returns an error, and also sends an error back to the HTTP client, and also closes the underlying read-closer. If the default behavior of `http.MaxBytesReader()` is not suitable for you, check its sources, copy it and modify it, it's relatively simple. Tune it to your needs.

Also note that you should not read everything (the uncompressed data) into memory. You may pass the "limited reader" to [`json.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder) which will read from the given reader while decoding the input JSON. Of course if the passed limited reader reports an error, the decoding will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Don't read everything into memory. Operate on a stream if possible. This is 100% possible in your example:

```
func ReadGzFile(filename string) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    fi, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return gzip.NewReader(fi)
}

func main() {
    b, err := ReadGzFile("test.gzip")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer b.Close()
    var dat map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(b).Decode(&dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dat)
}
```

This `Decode` approach has the side effect (which may or may not be desirable) of ignoring any garbage in the stream after the first valid JSON object.  In your case, this seems like a benefit. In some cases, it may not be.